# How to resolve "You can’t delete this auth provider as an authentication method because your org or Experience Cloud site is currently using it"?

Tags: sandbox, error-messages, experience-cloud, auth-provider, open-id-connect

#### How can Auth. Providers be removed from Experience Cloud sites?

When I attempt to delete my OpenID Auth. Provider in my Sandbox, I am receiving the following error:

> You can’t delete this auth provider as an authentication method because your org or Experience Cloud site is currently using it.

**See screenshot below:**

[image: You can’t delete this auth provider as an authentication method because your org or Experience Cloud site is currently using it.]

Other Auth. Providers can be deleted just fine.

I am not able to locate where to remove the Auth. Provider from the Experience Cloud site, and I am not able to find any additional information about this specific error.

Comment: Please do not use flagging to address down votes you feel you do not deserve. Mods have no ability to investigate nor reverse such votes.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar scenario in the past with this error. You can run below query

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, AuthConfigId, AuthProviderId FROM AuthConfigProviders where AuthProviderId='0SO*******'
```

which returns AuthConfigProviders id starting with '07T'that you use it in below

```
SELECT Id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById,DeveloperName,AuthOptionsAuthProvider,url from AuthConfig where Id='07T********'
```

Based on the lastmodifieddate and URL you should be able to figure out the usage.

In case there is recent no usage, you can [log a case with support](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000329621&type=1) to check if there are any Dangling Records on AuthConfig

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the reason that this Auth provider is being used in Named Credentials. If you can go to Setup => Named Credtials => open the list one by one and check whether any one them is using this Auth: provider. Once you remove the relation from here, you might be able to delete Auth: provider.